# How do I fix "incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'bool' to parameter of type 'bool (*)[9]'"? C

Tags: c, boolean

So I got a function that passes in bool as an input that I declared with `void check_Winner(bool locked_[9][9]);`

The error happens when I call it in "print_Winner" function:

```
bool locked[9][9];
void print_Winner(void)
{     
    
    for (int j=0;j<pair_count;j++) 
    {
        check_Winner(locked[0][j]);
    }
    
    return;
}
```

I dont understand why "incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'bool' to parameter of type 'bool (*)[9]' " occurs in the `check_Winner(locked[0][j]);` PS: pair_count<9

Comment: The `bool` array decays to a pointer in the function, so it's `[ignored][9]`; that's why you are getting `bool (*)[9]` as the message. Not related to your error, but good to know what the messages mean.

Comment: @Neil appreciate the info man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is taking in parameter an array:

```
void check_Winner(bool locked_[9][9]);
```

But the function call is providing a bool (`locked[0][j]` is a bool):

```
check_Winner(locked[0][j]);
```